# how to use grep -E with bytes after the match

Tags: grep

I try to grep like this:

```
grep -E '(UNIQ_23A0E66922726E9|UNIQ_23A0E66D943CFF3)' xst.sql
```

however I need some bytes (not lines) before and after the match.

if i use both -E and -P i got:

```
grep: conflicting matchers specified
```

I want functionality like

```
grep -o -P '.{0,10}UNIQ_23A0E66922726E9.{0,10}' xst.sql
```

but for all strings at once - in the example I have 2 but in reality I grep for 1000+.

Comment: Please add some example in- and output to make it clear what you want. Also please clarity: your command prints the whole line with the match, you say you want something before/after the match. Do you mean "match", or "matching line"?

Comment: This is not what the comment asked for. Data!

Comment: I posted update

Comment: This is not what I was asking for... I want input data and output data, not commands. Also, your new command will stop at line breaks. But a line break is also a byte.

Comment: and are these 1000+ strings all of the same type? If so, this might work for you: `grep -Po '.{0,10}(UNIQ_[0-9A-F]{15}).{0,10}' xst.sql`

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-E` tells GNU grep to use extended regular expressions (ERE), `-P` tells it to use Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE), which are a superset in functionality of ERE. Those are two different variants of the regex language, so indeed the options conflict with each other.

None of what you show needs PCRE though, so it seems you could just use

```
grep -o -E '.{0,10}(UNIQ_23A0E66922726E9|UNIQ_23A0E66D943CFF3).{0,10}' xst.sql
```

That would be a valid regex with the same meaning in PCRE, too. I'm not sure if there are performance differences between the ERE engine and the PCRE engine.

Comment: exactly what i wanted. I tried something like that but seems was different. works, will let you know when it matches something in 1-2 h